# "Затуманить" блок

Tags: jquery, блок, css

Доброго вечера.
Как можно "затуманить" нижнюю часть блока DIV?
Например как на сайте bebo.com - блок что справа.
Если можно с самописным примером.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, предположим у меня на сайте будет белый фон. Как мне можно "затуманить" любой DIV?
Приведите пожалуйста пример кода.

Comment: Делаете плашку-накладку, которую располагаете сверху над кусочком, который визуально закрывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаете для контейнера overflow: hidden; фиксированную высоту и снизу накладываете абсолютным позиционированием градиент, все.
Я не раз это писал и чувствую еще буду писать: когда хотите сделать что-то "как на этом сайте", то открывайте исходный код этого сайта и смотрите, что как и откуда растет.

Answer (score 0):

Это 2 фоновые картинки, главный фон идёт градиентом от розового к белому, а другая - фон сайдбара - она просто белого цвета с тенью. Итог - наложение белого на белое и есть такой эффект. А на счёт замутнения самого контента, это прозрачно-белый градиент снизу.
Есть 2 блока: один блок - блок с контентом, вторая - блок с градиентом (фоном, снизу), естественно ближе к юзеру (z-index).

Comment: Сдается, его интересует "туман" внизу блока, в который "уезжают" элементы.